# How can I read this analog gauge using Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, gauge

I want to read this analog gauge using Python and OpenCV, here is my starting point image:

[image: 1]

Actually, with some blur and contour detection I was able to clear it a little and draw some important parts:

[image: 2]

Here is my actual code:

```
import os
import glob
import cv2                       # to run code even if version changes
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('/home/administrator/Downloads/read_analogue_gauge_v1_1/images/gaugemio.jpg')
def rescaleFrame(frame, scale=0.5):
        width = int(frame.shape[1]*scale)
        height = int(frame.shape[0]*scale)
        dimensions = (width, height)
        return cv2.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized_image = rescaleFrame(img)
img = resized_image
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_hsv = cv2.bitwise_not(img_hsv)  # Convert to HSV space
lower_black, upper_black = np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([180, 255, 65])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_black, upper_black)

blank = np.zeros((747, 714), dtype='uint8')
blank2 = np.zeros((747, 714), dtype='uint8')
blurred = cv2.blur(~mask, (9, 9))

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1, 400, param1=50, param2=100, minRadius=200, maxRadius=0)
detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
dimension = img.shape

for(x, y, r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
    circle = cv2.circle(blank, (x,y),r, 255, -1 )
    cv2.circle(img, (x,y),r, (0,255,0),3)
    cv2.circle(img, (x,y),2, (0,0,255),3)
    cv2.circle(img, (x,y),30, (0,0,255),3)
    circ_col = x
    circ_row = y
bitwise_and = cv2.bitwise_and(blank, mask)
canny2 = cv2.Canny(bitwise_and, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
blurred2 = cv2.blur(bitwise_and, (15, 15))
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blurred2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('hi',resized_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any tips?

Comment: what do you mean? you already have the information you need, don't you? are you asking for polar transforms? present your research (googling). please review [ask].

Comment: I need to calculate a line from the center to the pointer, then calculate polar transforme angles

Comment: great. you have the center point (from any of the circles, hoping they all agree), and you have that green contour of the pointer. just find the point in that contour that is farthest away from the center. that'll be the tip.

Comment: I will try that, hope that farthest contour will be always the pointer tip and not the pointer gross part, thanks for your idea

Comment: What's the issue that you have?

Comment: When I wrote this question, how to continue with my code, right now, with Christoph help, I will search the most farthest point from the center, so I think that pointer angle will be my next problem

Comment: @Anibal Quiroz. Do you mean calculate the angle from centre to line?

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes, with the farthest point draw a line from the center the calculare their angle like a clock